# be used to/ used to

Tags: grammar

I am not sure whether to use **`be used to`** or **`used to`** in the following sentence.

Oscar has lived in Brazil for ten years. He (eat)_________________Brazilian food. it is his favorite food.

A. He was **used to** eating Brazilian food

B. He **used to eat** Brazilian food

Which one is correct .

With regards

Comment: What is your own guess, Yusuf, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Oscar has lived in Brazil for ten years.  He used to eat/ is used to eating Brazilian food. It's his favorite food.

As the sentence with the verb "live" is in the present present that means the same he has been living in Brazil for ten years, you should use here "is used to eating".
He is used to eating Brazilian food means that he is familiar with or accustomed to eating Brazilian food.

You use "used to eat" in the past tense. That means that he ate Brazilian food regularly or habitually and does not do that now, for example, Oscar lived in Brazil for ten years. He used to eat Brazilian food.

Answer (score 0):

Option B.

Option A contradicts the use of tense in your statements.

And the most preferred form of framing your sentence should be:

Oscar has lived in Brazil for ten years.He eats Brazilian food.it is his favorite food.